# Postgres: How to get SELECT to detect new insertions within a specific table

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, jdbc

I'm trying to execute an SQL query (`SELECT` operation) using the following Java code:

```
ResultSet resultSet = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tasks");
while (resultSet.next()) {
    while (1) {
        //loop infinitely until a worker executes the task
    }
}
```

But that is inefficient in the case when a new task gets added, as `SELECT` won't detect the new change ..

So, what is the Postgres SQL syntax that fetches the whole entries while detecting new insertions, within a specific table?

Comment: maybe if you search how to use a listener can help you, you can read about this here https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/83/listennotify.html

Comment: @YCF_L Thanks for the link. But I don't understand how to assure the sync between a notification and a `SELECT * FROM table` fetch operation.

Comment: did you search for triggers ?

Comment: @YCF_L Thanks for pointing this out - I seem to forget the `TRIGGER` operation ..

Comment: @YCF_L I'm not sure how I can execute the `trigger` after the `select`.

Comment: If you want to perform certain action for each inserted row then trigger on insert will surely suffice and select won't be necessary?

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński Depends why he's selecting. Watching new records because he needs some Java to do something outside the database? I know there's a PL/Java plugin available but the PL/* can be a bit awkward to work with outside of the database.

Comment: i aggree with @ŁukaszKamiński what i mean the select should be in the trigger you can onmy use that trigger to get information

Comment: @ŁukaszKamiński The application is intended to fetch from old record (before the app has ever started), and then get notified for new(fresh) insertions.

Comment: @Scoots As I explained to ŁukaszKamiński.

Comment: @Kais If using a trigger to do the full operation as the others have suggested in this thread is out of the question, you can use a trigger to insert into a secondary table, which is just a single column containing a reference to the primary key of `tasks`. Your select loop watches this secondary table, and deletes from it at the end of the loop

Comment: @Scoots I think the best solution, is to do a separated `trigger` operation.

Comment: Logical decoding: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/logicaldecoding.html  which is accessible through the JDBC driver: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/replication.html#logical-replication

Answer (score 0):

What you want sounds like change data capture (CDC), where you only want what was changed since you last queried the table.

to do that, you need a way to:
1. mark the rows that were changed
2. mark the rows that were already existent

The only way to do that is to:
1. keep a copy of the table so you can compare it against the table being updated/inserted.
2. use the audit columns within the table such as date_inserted, last_modified, etc. and pull the rows with dates after the last time you looked at the table.
3. Implement the table being updated as a slowly changing dimension.